# How do I configure WSO2 identity with LDAP?

Tags: ldap, wso2, identity, openldap, wso2-identity-server

How do I configure WSO2 identity with LDAP?

I changed my user-mgt.xml to:

```
    <UserManager>
    <Realm>
        <Configuration>
            <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
            <AdminUser>
            <UserName>admin</UserName>
            <Password>admin</Password>
            </AdminUser>
        <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName>
        <Property name="url">jdbc:h2:repository/database/WSO2CARBON_DB;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</Property>
        <Property name="userName">wso2carbon</Property>
        <Property name="password">wso2carbon</Property>
        <Property name="driverName">org.h2.Driver</Property>
        <Property name="maxActive">50</Property>
        <Property name="maxWait">60000</Property>
        <Property name="minIdle">5</Property>
        </Configuration>

        <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ApacheDSUserStoreManager">
        <Property name="ReadOnly">true</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldap://ldap.curitiba.pr.gov.br:389</Property>
        <Property name="ConnectionName">o=ICI</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=person)</Property>
        <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">wso2Person</Property>
        <Property name="UserSearchBase">ou=users,dc=ICI,ou=domains,o=ICI</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(uid=?))</Property>
        <Property name="UserNameAttribute">uid</Property>
        <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">[\\S]{5,30}</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">[\\S]{3,30}</Property>
        <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">^[^~!@#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">[\\S]{3,30}</Property>
        <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">^[^~!@#$;%^*+={}\\|\\\\&lt;&gt;]{3,30}$</Property>
        <Property name="ReadLDAPGroups">false</Property>
        <Property name="WriteLDAPGroups">false</Property>
        <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">false</Property>
        <Property name="GroupSearchBase">ou=Groups,dc=wso2,dc=org</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectClass=groupOfNames)</Property>
        <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">groupOfNames</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=groupOfNames)(cn=?))</Property>
        <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
        <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
        <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
        </UserStoreManager> 
    </Realm>
    </UserManager>
```

but it doesn't work.

Here is the contents of the log:

```
[2012-08-20 18:32:03,209]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2012-08-20 18:32:03,209]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Operating System : Linux 2.6.37.6-smp, i386
[2012-08-20 18:32:03,209]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Home        : /usr/lib/java
[2012-08-20 18:32:03,209]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Version     : 1.6.0_25
[2012-08-20 18:32:03,210]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java VM          : Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM 20.0-b11,Sun Microsystems Inc.
[2012-08-20 18:32:03,210]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Carbon Home      : /soa/srvapp/IdentityServer
[2012-08-20 18:32:03,210]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  Java Temp Dir    : /soa/srvapp/IdentityServer/tmp
[2012-08-20 18:32:03,210]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} -  User             : root, en-US, America/Sao_Paulo
[2012-08-20 18:32:06,645]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.configuration.LDAPConfigurationBuilder} -  KDC server is disabled.
[2012-08-20 18:32:06,649]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.DirectoryActivator} -  Initializing Directory Server with working directory /soa/srvapp/IdentityServer/repository/data/org.wso2.carbon.directory and port 10390
[2012-08-20 18:32:10,665] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator} -  Cannot start User Manager Core bundle
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.config.RealmConfigXMLProcessor.buildRealmConfiguration(RealmConfigXMLProcessor.java:170)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.buildBootStrapRealmConfig(DefaultRealmService.java:150)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:86)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:124)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:64)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:54)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$1.run(BundleContextImpl.java:782)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:773)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:754)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:352)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.resume(AbstractBundle.java:370)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.Framework.resumeBundle(Framework.java:1068)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.resumeBundles(StartLevelManager.java:557)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.incFWSL(StartLevelManager.java:464)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.doSetStartLevel(StartLevelManager.java:248)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.StartLevelManager.dispatchEvent(StartLevelManager.java:445)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:220)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:330)
```

Comment: please attach the full log. Need to look into the full stack trace. What is the type of the LDAP user store you are tying to get connected to ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a part of the full stacktrace. Anyhow I see an obvious invalid configuration in user-mgt.xml. You have used an organizational unit object as the connection name which is wrong.

```
<Property name="ConnectionName">o=ICI</Property>
```

You have to use a valid user in OpenLDAP as the connection name. For example,

```
<Property name="ConnectionName">cn=SomeUser,ou=users,dc=ICI,ou=domains,o=ICI</Property>
```

Comment: I Understand, now is this log:

`2012-08-21 16:21:09,694] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.LDAPUserStoreManager} -  Carbon cannot function without an Admin Username`

Comment: Previously you were using the ApacheDSUserStoreManager which works in Read/Write mode. But now I see you are using the LDAPUserStoreManager which works only in the ReadOnly mode. So please make sure you have user with the name "admin" in the OpenLDAP. This is the username you defined as 
<UserName>admin</UserName> in the <AdminUser> configuration.

Comment: SureshAtt, sorry, but I can only login with the User in <UserName>admin</UserName> the users in ldap not :(

Comment: You have to provide login permissions for other users. You can create roles, assign permission to those roles and add users to those roles. By default all users are assigned to the everyone role which doesn't have the login permission. Recommended approach is to create a role, provide login permission and add users to that role.

Comment: I understand, you know how i integrate with wso2 registry ?